# How to build FourSquare like leaderboard (users above and below you)

Tags: mysql, arrays, list, leaderboard

I'm looking for a way to implement Foursquare's style of leaderboard where instead of showing you the top 10 for example it shows the you 2 people above you and 2 people below you between your friends.

I'm hoping to avoid having to pull down everyones scores and do some array manipulation. Is there anyway I can do this with a smart SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (assuming table USER has an integer column SCORE):

```
select * from USER where SCORE < myscore order by SCORE DESC limit 2;

select * from USER where SCORE >= myscore order by SCORE ASC limit 2;
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: The only catch here is that if there are many users of the same score that could plausibly show up, it will appear random each time you refresh.  You can resolve this by adding another order constraint, like ID.

Comment: Would two separate SQL statements be faster than one + a search? I'd think making an extra call would be more expensive?

Comment: All depends on network latency (localhost would be none), but db calls are usually extremely fast since they are optimized, especially when you use indexes.